# Get Users available based on validation of status, id, and time spread across 3 tables

Tags: mysql

Lets say I want to pull a list of users(From TableA) who:

- are currently within `Status = 2`
- and

  - currently not in TableB,

    - OR
  - are in TableB.UserId AND (TableB.AppId > 1year) by comparing the dates between TableC.id's CreatedDate and with the CurrentDate.

Current Schema Setup...

```
TableA (UserID)
--------------------------------------
id | fName   | lName    | Status | CreatedDate
1  | John    | Doe      | 2      | 2017-03-02 06:31:15.482
2  | Marry   | Jane     | 2      | 2017-05-03 16:43:56.937
3  | William | Thompson | 4      | 2017-06-15 13:12:32.219
4  | Timothy | Limmons  | 2      | 2017-09-27 01:52:42.842

TableB
--------------------------------------
id | AppID | UserID | CreatedDate
1  | 2     | 1      | 2019-04-16 23:21:56.099
2  | 3     | 4      | 2019-08-03 04:32:18.472


TableC (AppID)
--------------------------------------
id | Title              | CreatedDate
1  | ToDo List          | 2017-03-09 22:45:12.907
2  | Magic Marshmellows | 2018-11-14 07:01:04.050
3  | Project Falcon     | 2019-07-23 14:22:44.837
```

The info above should pull users from TableA with the id's of 1 and 2.

- Marry has not been paired with an App, and is therefor available
- John is paired with the App Magic Marshmellows, but the project began over 1 year ago and is therefor available

The following info should NOT pull users with the id's of 3 and 4.

- William is a status of 4 (not 2) and is therefor NOT available.
- Timothy is paired with the App Project Falcon, and this app began within a year from the current DateTime (12/15/2019)... and is therefor NOT available

I need something like...

```
Select *
FROM
    [TableA] a
WHERE
    a.Status = 2
    IF
        TableB.UserID NOT CONTAINS a.id
    ELSE IF
        TableB.UserID = a.id
        AND WHERE
            TableB.AppID = TableC.id
            AND WHERE
            TableC.CreatedDate is less than 1 year old from Current Date
```

I'm just not sure how to go about using the right syntax for this. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. If there is a better title for this complicated question, please let me know.

Comment: are you sure you are using mysql?

Comment: yeah, it's with sql server in regards to tables and stored procedures. Basically if this can be done via stored procedure, I would prefer to do it this way. Otherwise I will have to write this in C#, and pull way more unnecessary data to parse through than I need to.

Also, I just edited a few things to make it more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN MYSQL you would do a query like this.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE UserID
>     (`id` int, `fName` varchar(7), `lName` varchar(8), `Status` int, `CreatedDate` Date)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO UserID
>     (`id`, `fName`, `lName`, `Status`, `CreatedDate`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'John', 'Doe', 1, '2017-03-02 06:31:15.482'),
>     (2, 'Marry', 'Jane', 2, '2017-05-03 16:43:56.937'),
>     (3, 'William', 'Thompson', 4, '2017-06-15 13:12:32.219'),
>     (4, 'Timothy', 'Limmons', 2, '2017-09-27 01:52:42.842')
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE TableB
>     (`id` int, `AppID` int, `UserID` int, `CreatedDate` Date)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO TableB
>     (`id`, `AppID`, `UserID`, `CreatedDate`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 2, 1, '2019-04-16 23:21:56.099'),
>     (2, 3, 4, '2019-08-03 04:32:18.472')
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE APPID
>     (`id` int, `Title` varchar(18), `CreatedDate` Date)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO APPID
>     (`id`, `Title`, `CreatedDate`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'ToDo List', '2017-03-09 22:45:12.907'),
>     (2, 'Magic Marshmellows', '2018-11-14 07:01:04.050'),
>     (3, 'Project Falcon', '2019-07-23 14:22:44.837')
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT u.* 
> From UserID u LEFT JOIN TableB b ON u.id = b.UserID
> LEFT JOIN APPID a ON b.APPID = a.id
> WHERE Status = 2
> AND (u.id NOT IN (SELECT UserID FROM TableB)
>      OR (u.id IN (SELECT UserID FROM TableB) AND a.CreatedDate >  NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR));
> ```
>
> ```
> id | fName   | lName   | Status | CreatedDate
> -: | :------ | :------ | -----: | :----------
>  4 | Timothy | Limmons |      2 | 2017-09-27 
>  2 | Marry   | Jane    |      2 | 2017-05-03
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM APPID WHERE `CreatedDate` >   NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
> ```
>
> ```
> id | Title          | CreatedDate
> -: | :------------- | :----------
>  3 | Project Falcon | 2019-07-23
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d6ca2a28c68acfc7980d76e70743c43a)*

Comment: hmm really close. John should be in the first query instead of Timothy. I also changed the last line to `OR (a.id IN (SELECT UserID FROM TableB) AND DATEADD(year, 1, c.CreatedDate) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP));`, due to many squiggly lines. Also John should have a `Status` of 2 (this was my bad, updated the question). This definitely has me thinking in the right direction. Hopefully I can debug from here.

Comment: Forgot to update the `Status` (also changed to StatusNum, since Status seems to be a keyword) myself. So the above line is working for me.

Comment: A bit strange to see query as accepted while it get records 2, 4 while expected results by OP should be 1, 2 :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM 
    TableA AS a
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
              b.UserID
        FROM
            TableB AS b
            INNER JOIN TableC AS c ON (
                b.AppID = c.id
            )
        WHERE
            c.CreatedDate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
    ) AS s ON (
        a.id = s.UserID
    )
WHERE
    a.Status = 2
    AND s.UserID IS NULL
```

OR

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM 
    TableA AS a
    LEFT JOIN TableB AS b ON (
        b.UserID = a.id
    )
    LEFT JOIN TableC AS c ON (
        c.id = b.AppID
    )
WHERE
    a.Status = 2
    AND (
           b.UserID IS NULL
        OR c.CreatedDate < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
    )
```

OR

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM 
    TableA AS a
WHERE
    a.Status = 2
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
              *
        FROM
            TableB AS b
            INNER JOIN TableC AS c ON (
                b.AppID = c.id
            )
        WHERE
            b.UserID = a.id
            AND c.CreatedDate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
    )
```

=>

```
id  fName   lName   Status  CreatedDate
1   John    Doe 2   2017-03-02
2   Marry   Jane    2   2017-05-03
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TableA` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fName` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lName` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Status` (`Status`,`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DELETE FROM `TableA`;
INSERT INTO `TableA` (`id`, `fName`, `lName`, `Status`, `CreatedDate`) VALUES
    (1, 'John', 'Doe', 2, '2017-03-02'),
    (2, 'Marry', 'Jane', 2, '2017-05-03'),
    (3, 'William', 'Thompson', 4, '2017-06-15'),
    (4, 'Timothy', 'Limmons', 2, '2017-09-27');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TableB` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `AppID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UserID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `AppID` (`AppID`),
  KEY `UserID` (`UserID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DELETE FROM `TableB`;
INSERT INTO `TableB` (`id`, `AppID`, `UserID`, `CreatedDate`) VALUES
    (1, 2, 1, '2019-04-16'),
    (2, 3, 4, '2019-08-03');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TableC` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Title` varchar(18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `CreatedDate` (`CreatedDate`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DELETE FROM `TableC`;
INSERT INTO `TableC` (`id`, `Title`, `CreatedDate`) VALUES
    (1, 'ToDo List', '2017-03-09 22:45:12'),
    (2, 'Magic Marshmellows', '2018-11-14 07:01:04'),
    (3, 'Project Falcon', '2019-07-23 14:22:44');
```

**UPDATED: WHERE condition fixed**